# When reading .xlsx file using POI I got an error "Zip File is closed"

Tags: java, excel, zip, apache-poi

```
public Sheet readExcel() throws Exception{
    //File fi=new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))+"\\src\\testdata2.xls");
    File fi=new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\workspace\\HMS\\src\\testdata\\testdata1.xlsx");

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet  Sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowCount = Sheet.getLastRowNum()-Sheet.getFirstRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
        Row row = Sheet.getRow(i);

        if(row.getCell(0).toString().length()==0){

            System.out.println(row.getCell(1).toString()+"----"+ row.getCell(2).toString()+"----"+

            row.getCell(3).toString()+"----"+ row.getCell(4).toString());
        }
    }    
    return Sheet;   
}
```

By running above code am getting error like this........

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File
>   is closed
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:45)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:186)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:254)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:201)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:294)
>       at ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:16)
>       at ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:30)

Can anyone help me tracing out what exactly is the problem.

I Googled but couldn't get the solution!

Comment: What is the connection with webdriver that you set these tags?

Answer (score 11):

To read an xslx file use create an object of FileInputStream class

```
    //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file

    File file = new File("path/filename.xlsx");

    //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    //create object of XSSFWorkbook class

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

Hope this heps you...

Answer (score 0):

Try shortening the file name and file path. Looks like there is a limit on how long the characters can be between " and ". It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to pass a ***FileInputStream*** when creating a ***XSSFWorkbook*** object, you can also pass an absolute path+filename as a String and it can be quite long (works for me with 101 characters, 108 characters with the double slashes, could probably be longer). I just wrote a small local app under Windows 7 whose only argument is a property file containing (among other properties) the absolute path+filename of the .xlsx file that I want to deal with (example property format : `datasetFile=C:\\Users\\jlm\\Documents\\Test Cases\\AAAS\\TestCase2JsonGenerator\\AAAS_g1.xlsx`). I just pass the **datasetFile** property as parameter to the **XSSFWorkbook** constructor (example code line : `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(tags.get("datasetFile"));` ). It works just fine, BUT don't forget any of the double slashes otherwise you get the "Zip File is closed" exception (about 2 hours lost).